# find indices according to input string operator

Tags: matlab

Lets suppose we have a vector in a function

```
b = 1:100
```

The input to the function would be a condition and threshold like `('<' , 10)`

and the function returns the indices which are greater than , greater than equal to , equal to etc

A conventional way would be to make list of `ifs` something like

```
if(strcmp('>',condition))
    indices = find(b > threshold)
```

for each operator but what if i just want to do it in one line like if the input condition is greater than `>`operater the `find()` function simply finds b greater than the threshold instead of making if for each operator

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass an operator as an input string? Couldn't you directly pass function handles to functions `ge`, `gt`, `le` and `lt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state in the comments, using `eval` is not good pratice. However, passing operators as strings will force you to do so, meaning you either have to use it, or you'll have to change the inputs to your function.

If you don't want to be forced to use `eval`, instead of passing a string representing an operator to the function, you'd rather want to pass it directly a handle to one of these functions :

1. `ge` : Greater or equal
2. `gt` : Greater than
3. `le` : Lower or equal
4. `lt` : Lower

The function (I'll let you do the error/wrong input checking) would be :

```
function out=Myfun(FunHandle,Threshold)

    b=1:100;

    out=find(FunHandle(b,Threshold));

end
```

### Outputs :

```
Myfun(@ge,90)

  Columns 1 through 8

  90    91    92    93    94    95    96    97

  Columns 9 through 11

  98    99   100



Myfun(@lt,12)


  Columns 1 through 8

  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

  Columns 9 through 11

  9    10    11
```

Comment: Thanks ! a much better solution

Comment: @Umar If you want to use `'<'` etc as input, you can apply `str2func` to it: `function out=Myfun(funStr,Threshold); b = 1:100; funHandle = str2func(funStr); out=find(funHandle(b,Threshold));`

Comment: @LuisMendo even Bill's solution works but your function was what i was looking for , thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

use MATLAB's [eval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) function:

```
eval(['indices = find(b' op num2str(t) ')'])
```

where op is a string, contains the specific operation ('<','>','>=' etc), and t is the threshold.

**Example**

```
b = 1:10;
op = '>';
t = 4;
eval(['indices = find(b' op num2str(t) ')'])
```

result:

```
indices =

 5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer but I am somehow told that using eval is not a good practice , +1 for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`

Example:

```
operator = '<';
number = 10;
threshold = 3;

condition = [num2str(number) operator num2str(thr)];
eval(condition)
```

Will return `False`, since `number` is not `lower` than `thr`. Try changing `<` for `>` and will evaluate `True`

Comment: Well, specifying operators as input string is even worse as it forces you to use `eval` ..